# How to let user select only local files using Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-file

I need to let the user select a file from their local storage for my application. Right now I'm using `INTENT.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to let the user select the file, but it also gives the option of selecting URI from the cloud. After I get the URI file, I treat it as a local file and perform various things (including extracting the file extension). How can I let the user only pick local files?

```
else if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.action_import_from_file){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Pick a file"), REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_FILE_FOR_IMPORT);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try using [Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY) like 
    `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);`
If the gallery app in your device supports it, only files in local storage will be displayed. If the gallery app does not support the above intent, you can show an error message to the user after checking the file length of the returned file path from gallery app.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
 startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_PHOTO_FOR_AVATAR);
```

try this  use `setType()` method and specify what file type to choose by user

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
i.setType("application/pdf|application/x-excel|text/csv");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Pick a file"), REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_FILE_FOR_IMPORT);
```

you can also use array of MIME types like below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
String[] types = {"application/x-excel/*", "application/csv/*",};
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Pick a file"), REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_FILE_FOR_IMPORT);
```

Comment: does xlsx and csv files come under application? I'm importing datasets from excel files, csv files etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for only open csv and xlsx file
it will select only csv and xlsx file

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    String[] mimetypes = {"application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
    officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "text/csv"}; 
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```